# "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer" after "curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock localhost"

Tags: django, sockets, curl, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy a django app to DigitalOcean but when I try to activate gunicorn with `curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock localhost` it says `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.
I'm literally following a tutorial made by digitalocean but it doesn't shows how to solve this error. What do I have to change?

**my /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=sammy
EnviromentFile=/home/sammy/mysite/env
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/mysite
ExecStart=/home/sammy/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          mysite/locallibrary.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**my /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```